# The association fixtures symfony

Tags: php, symfony, fixtures

I'm trying to work on a symfony project. I created my file fixtures I want to add a key for my table 
to make `club.$key` to send to my database and create several club

```
class ClubFixtures extends Fixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface
{

public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{

    $this->loadClubs($manager);

}

/**
 * @param ObjectManager $manager
 * @throws BadMethodCallException
 */
private function loadClubs(ObjectManager $manager)
{

    foreach ($this->getClubData() as [ $establishmentName, $address, $code]) {
        $club = new Club();
        $club->setEstablishmentName($establishmentName);
        $club->setAddress($address);
        $club->setCode($code);
        $club->addUsers($this->getReference('user1'));
        $club->addGames($this->getReference('game1'));
        $manager->persist($club);
        $manager->flush();
        $this->addReference('club1', $club);

    }
}

private function getClubData(): array
{
    return [
        // $clubData = [$establishmentName, $address, $code, $user, $games];
        ['establishmentName1', '60 rue de belleville', 342],
        ['establishmentName2', '65 rue de jaures', 543],
        ['establishmentName3', '80 rue de stalingrad', 987]
    ];
}


/**
 * Get the order of this fixture
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getOrder()
{
    return 1;
}
```

I am a beginner in this domain.

Comment: So, what is a question?)

Comment: I want to add a key to my array like $key to make
$this-> addReference ('club'. $key, $club);

Comment: if I had one  value ds the table I can do that: foreach ($this->getClubData() as $key =>[ $establishmentName, $address, $code]) {
            $club = new Club();
            $club->setEstablishmentName($establishmentName);
            $club->setAddress($address);
            $club->setCode($code);
            $club->addUsers($this->getReference('user1'));
            $club->addGames($this->getReference('game1'));
            $manager->persist($club);
            $manager->flush();
            $this->addReference('club'.$key, $club);

        }
    }

Comment: Please don't put code and explanation that should be in the question in comments. [edit] the question to update it with details. Also, read [ask]. We need to know what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get.

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: my references are not working, i cant add the reference betwen two entities where there ara associations

Comment: I have this error  php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load
Careful, database will be purged. Do you want to continue y/N ?y
  > purging database
  > loading [1] App\DataFixtures\ClubFixtures
  > loading [2] App\DataFixtures\UserFixtures

In ReferenceRepository.php line 163:

  Reference to: (etablissement 1) does not exist

Answer (score 1):

You have an error using [foreach function](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

So, your code here should be like this:

```
foreach ($this->getClubData() as $key => list($establishmentName, $address, $code)) {
    $club = new Club();
    $club->setEstablishmentName($establishmentName);
    $club->setAddress($address);
    $club->setCode($code);
    $club->addUsers($this->getReference('user1'));
    $club->addGames($this->getReference('game1'));
    $manager->persist($club);
    $manager->flush();
    $this->addReference('club'.$key, $club);
}
```

Also, it is very useful to check [your logs](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/logging.html#where-logs-are-stored). This way you can more faster find the cause and fix it, or just copying it here.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for what want to be inspired:
  user club association

class UserFixtures extends Fixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface
{

```
private $passwordEncoder;


public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
{
    $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;

}

public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{
    $this->loadUsers($manager);
}

/**
 * @param ObjectManager $manager
 * @throws \Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\BadMethodCallException
 */
private function loadUsers(ObjectManager $manager)
{

    foreach ($this->getUserData() as $key => [$name, $username, $email, $birthdate, $password, $address, $userCode,
             $roles, $token, $service, $picture, $pictureName, $status]) {
        $user = new User();
        $user->setName($name);
        $user->setUsername($username);
        $user->setEmail($email);
        $user->setBirthdate($birthdate);
        $user->setPassword($this->passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $password));
        $user->setAddress($address);
        $user->setUserCode($userCode);
        $user->setRoles($roles);
        $user->setToken($token);
        $user->setService($service);
        $user->setPicture($picture);
        $user->setPictureName($pictureName);
        $user->setStatus($status);
        $user->setClub($this->getReference('club1'));
        $manager->persist($user);
        $this->addReference('user' . $key, $user);


    }
    $manager->flush();

}

private function getUserData(): array
{

    return [
        ['Jane Doe', 'jane_admin', 'jane_admin@symfony.com', new \DateTime('2008-10-12'), 'test', '45 rue de tourtille', 139879, 'ROLE_ADMIN', 'jdijididi43gf', 'admin', 'image1', 'mon profil', 1],
        ['Tom Doe', 'tom_admin', 'tom_admin@symfony.com', new \DateTime('2009-10-11 '), 'test', '46 rue de tourtille', 135879, 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN', 'di43gfjdijididi', 'super_admin', 'image2', 'profil', 1],
        ['John Doe', 'john_user', 'john_user@symfony.com', new \DateTime('2010-09-10 '), 'test', '43 rue de tourtille', 139797, 'ROLE_USER', 'jdijidikaoli43gf', 'marketing', 'image3', 'ma phot', 1]
    ];
}

/**
 * Get the order of this fixture
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getOrder()
{
    return 2;
}
```

class ClubFixtures extends Fixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface
{

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{

    $this->loadClubs($manager);

}

/**
 * @param ObjectManager $manager
 * @throws BadMethodCallException
 */
private function loadClubs(ObjectManager $manager)
{

    foreach ($this->getClubData() as $key => [$establishmentName, $address, $code]) {
        $club = new Club();
        $club->setEstablishmentName($establishmentName);
        $club->setAddress($address);
        $club->setCode($code);
        $manager->persist($club);
        $this->addReference('club'.$key, $club);


    }
    $manager->flush();
}

private function getClubData(): array
{
    return [
        // $clubData = [$establishmentName, $address, $code];
        ['establishmentName1', '60 rue de belleville', 342],
        ['establishmentName2', '65 rue de jaures', 543],
        ['establishmentName3', '80 rue de stalingrad', 987]
    ];
}


/**
 * Get the order of this fixture
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getOrder()
{
    return 1;
}
```